# How can you present modal UIViewControllers in MonoTouch using MvvmCross?

Tags: uiviewcontroller, xamarin.ios, modal-dialog, mvvmcross

By adding `IMvxModalTouchView` to `MyView`, let the view become modal. But, I cannot change it at runtime. i.e. `MyView` must be modal every time.  Is it possible to make it more flexible, let say, `Show(MvxShowViewModelRequest view, bool isModal);` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This area of MvvmCross is called "preesentation"

Other Mvvm frameworks may refer to it as "INavigationService"

Within MvvmCross, the presenter on each platform is 100% overrideable. Some examples and source code links are provided on http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/06/presenter-roundup.html

If you want to implement some custom navigation hint, then:

- all `ShowViewModel` calls have an `presentationHint` parameter - https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3.1/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross/ViewModels/MvxNavigatingObject.cs#L40
- the presenters receive these hints in the `PresentationValues` property of the `MvxViewModelRequest` in the `Show` call